# gui builder for shell script

Tags: gui, scripts

Is there any gui builder tool for shell script. So that the interface can be designed by click and drag. Is there any plugins for eclipse or any existing ide to do this?

Comment: A GUI for a shell script? What for? Can you give an example?

Answer (score 2):

Bash is a Shell. A shell is a command-line interpreter, an interface for you to call other programs/commands. That's why it is called **Command Line Interface** or CLI. So, a shell scripting language provides constructs that facilitates this interaction (sometimes some CLI tools via builtin), but rarely provides any GUI tools to build graphical interface. It's not a full-fledge language with its own graphical components. You can use these shells to call other CLI tools (most commonly) and sometimes a GUI tool (like [zenity](http://library.gnome.org/users/zenity/stable/)).

Since Shells never provide GUI building support, there can be no question of having a GUI building tool for them.

Yes, as I already have said, you can use [zenity](http://library.gnome.org/users/zenity/stable/) or other similar tools to bring GUI components, but those are all third party libraries called from bash, not bash things themselves (Zenity is a GNOME tool).

Check this answer to a similar [question here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/119009/19288) on Unix SE site. Also check this question on Stack overflow

- [How to make a GUI for bash scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/928019/how-to-make-a-gui-for-bash-scripts)